# .net core 2.0 Resolver issue with identityrole

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I customised the IdentityRole users key to be int instead of string. and this is how I have tried to add it to the service collection.

First of all my Application user inherits from identityUser

`public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>......`

then in my service collection:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int>>(options => {
            // Password settings
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;.......`
```

In a base controller I have the following constructor:

```
public BaseApiController(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<BaseApiController> logger) : base(logger)
        {
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _configuration = configuration;

            _jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { Formatting = Formatting.Indented };
        }
```

Then I use the base controller on one of my mvc controllers in the form:

```
 public class RegisterController : BaseApiController
    {
        private readonly IAccountService _accountService;

        public RegisterController(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<RegisterController> logger, IAccountService accountService) : base(roleManager, userManager, configuration, logger)
        {
            _accountService =  accountService;

        }
```

now when I run using swagger I receive the following error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request Unable to
>   resolve service for type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identnty.RoleManager
>   While attempting to activate
>   Myprog.Areas.Account.Controllers.RegisterController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base controller needed to have the  assigned in the call and then followed through on all implementations:

```
public BaseApiController(RoleManager<IdentityRole<int>> roleManager, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<BaseApiController> logger) : base(logger)
```